# Replace Oracle sysdate for Oracle datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oracle, datagrid

I have a query I want to populate in a Visual Studio datagrid that is returning an Oracle Invalid Character error.

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE join_date < sysdate;
```

The above query will work in Oracle SQL developer, but I am getting the error with Visual Studio. Is this caused by the 'sysdate' keyword? If so, what should I use instead? C#

Comment: what type is 'join_date'?

Comment: I try to avoid `SELECT *` type queries as they don't give you full control.  What happens if a LOB is added to that table?  Your application probably won't be able to handle that.

Comment: You should post your C# code where you are executing this statement...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon.  The semicolon is needed in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer in order to signify where one statement ends and the next begins.  Since you're only sending a single statement in your C# API, the semicolon is not a valid character.